# gulp.less import not working when change imported less

Tags: gulp, less, watch, gulp-browser-sync

Web page is updated when I change the file which is imported in `main.less`, but styles from imported less file don't change in completed main.min.css

--gulpfile.js--

```
gulp.task('browser-sync', function() {
browsersync({
    proxy: "nika.local",
    notify: false
})
});

gulp.task('styles', function() {
return gulp.src('app/less/**/*.less')
.pipe(less())
.pipe(rename({ suffix: '.min', prefix : '' }))
.pipe(autoprefixer(['last 15 versions']))
.pipe(gulp.dest('app/css'))
.pipe(browsersync.reload( {stream: true} ))
});

gulp.task('watch', ['styles', 'js', 'browser-sync'], function() {
gulp.watch('app/less/**/*.less', ['styles']);
});

gulp.task('default', ['watch']);
```

--main.less--

```
//main.less
@import url("block/home-page.less");
```

Comment: Aren't less imports just @import "block/home-page.less"   [no url()]

Comment: See four or five last [`[gulp] [less]`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gulp+less) questions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49618710, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49132742, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49416905, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49529313,
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49350880 etc.